# Data Studio not Calculating Cost Per Lead correctly?

Tags: formula, looker-studio

Does anybody know why Data Studio doesn't give the correct CPL calculation? For instance, my spend is £336 with 44 leads. Instead of showing the correct CPL (around £7.60) it's showing £90.17.

I've tried doing a custom field using the formula variations (cost)/website leads & cost/(website leads) which have worked for previous dashboards like Funnel but it's still showing the same results.

If anybody could help with this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `sum(cost)/sum(website leads)` as the formula?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out the attribution window was set on 28 d click + 7d view for this specific event when the Facebook campaign was actually set on 7d click + 1 day view. Fixing this got me the right numbers